# Why DateTimeToMilliseconds in DateUtils.pas is marked as internal?

Tags: delphi

Why DateTimeToMilliseconds in DateUtils.pas is marked as internal?
Can I use it?

```
{ Internal, converts a date-time to milliseconds }
function DateTimeToMilliseconds(const ADateTime: TDateTime): Int64;
var
  LTimeStamp: TTimeStamp;
begin
  LTimeStamp := DateTimeToTimeStamp(ADateTime);
  Result := LTimeStamp.Date;
  Result := (Result * MSecsPerDay) + LTimeStamp.Time;
end;
```

[Delphi XE]

---

I have found this on About.com:

> Experience shows that creating two TDateTime values using the function and EncodeDateTime that are distant from each other only a millisecond, the function returns a MillisecondsBetween not return as was expected, proving that it is not accurate.

So, if I don't care about few milisecs, I should use it.

Comment: What version of Delphi are you using?  The DateUtils unit had a major overhaul in XE that made these functions all extremely accurate down to the millisecond.

Comment: I have Delphi XE Professional

Comment: That About.com article refers to an old version of Delphi - I couldn't see a date, but probably Delphi 7. If you follow the links in it you eventually end up in a QC report showing the exact code you're quoting as a fix! It has subsequently been added to Delphi, as noted by @NickHodges above and me below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `TDateTime` is a floating point double. To minimize rounding errors when working with `TDateTime` values, most calculations in DateUtils converts the `TDateTime` to milliseconds.

Later when calculations are ready the `Int64` value is converted back to a `TDateTime` value again.

The `internal` marking is to emphasize that this function is an implementation detail, not to be utilized outside the library. That is, when working with `TDateTime` values, use the public functions/procedures.

This is a little test of the function `MilliSecondsBetween`:

```
program TestMSecBetween;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses 
  System.SysUtils,System.DateUtils;

var
  d1,d2 : TDateTime;
  i,iSec,iMin,iHour,iMSec;
  isb : Int64;
begin
  d1 := EncodeDateTime(2013,6,14,0,0,0,0);
  for i := 0 to 1000*60*60*24-1 do
  begin
    iHour := (i div (1000*60*60)) mod 24;
    iMin := (i div (1000*60)) mod 60;
    iSec := (i div 1000) mod 60;
    iMSec := i mod 1000;
    d2 := EncodeDateTime(2013,6,14,iHour,iMin,iSec,iMSec);
    isb := MilliSecondsBetween(d2,d1);
    if (isb <> i) then
      WriteLn(i:10,iHour:3,iMin:3,iSec:3,iMSec:4,isb:3);
  end;
  ReadLn;
end.
```

You can expand the test for more than one day to see if there are some anomalies.

Comment: For more information see this [Delphi.about.com article](http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/a/accurate-difference-between-two-delphi-tdatetime-values.htm) where it mentions the source of this method, a [proposal by John Herbster](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=56957) for improving the accuracy of the date/time methods.  If you want to use this method yourself, make a local copy.  Don't edit the original DateUtils.pas for something as minor as this.

Comment: > Experience shows that creating two TDateTime values using the function and EncodeDateTime that are distant from each other only a millisecond, the function returns a MillisecondsBetween not return as was expected, proving that it is not accurate.     ---------------------------------------    so if I don't care about few milisec I can use it?

Comment: You can copy the function and use it, yes. But first make sure that it is really necessary. Most practical ways to work with TDateTime values should be covered by SysUtils and DateUtils.

Comment: Please note that since Delphi-2009 (I think) the accuracy of DateUtils calculations was improved (much by the work of John Herbster).

Comment: @NickHodges is correct, Delphi-XE has the improved DateUtils library. It can also be found here, [`DateUtils.pas`](https://bitbucket.org/NickHodges/nickdemocode/src/7390f3923b9ce199fb713926e58a14e24441e2f5/UnitTesting/DateStuff/DateUtils.pas).

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason you could not use it, it is not deprecated and used internally.

It's just marked as 'internal' because the function header is not in the interface section. If you copy the header there it should work.

What we always do if we 'patch' a third-party unit like this, is copying it to a directory in our own search path (named PatchLibs) before modifying. That way you can't 'damage' the original file and you don't have to worry about how to rebuild the original units.

Comment: Don't edit the VCL / RTL source for something as minor as this!  You should be very cautious editing the VCL source - you miss out on updates and patches and can cause compatibility issues. Do it only for major, important bug fixes that cannot be solved any other way.  For something like this, just make a copy of the method somewhere else.